# Web3j 5.0.0 and event listener

Tags: web3j, infura, gas-price

I'm using Web3j 5.0.0. I would listen to events of a smart contract. So, I write

```
      this.getContract().tokenMintedEventFlowable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, 
                         DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
            .subscribe(new TokenMintedEventConsumer()

 ...
public class TokenMintedEventConsumer implements Consumer
{ 
@Override
public void accept(Object t) throws Exception
{
   TheContract.TokenMintedEventResponse event= 
   (TheContract.TokenMintedEventResponse)t; 
   System.out.println("Token Minted: "+event.creator+" "+ event.tokenId);   
}
}
```

for each event i would listen (about 8 events). Now, i have two main problems:

1) Using Ganache, some events get not listened to. I have cheched the transaction on Ganache,  they are correctly performed, but the related event are not catched.

2) Using Infura (both https and wss), I receive the errors

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | Invalid response received: 404; 404 page not found
```

and `org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.ClientConnectionException: Invalid response received: 404; 404 page not found`

Additionally, the latter error is also raised if I call the web3j method

```
 ethGasPrice().send().getGasPrice()
```

I suppose that event listener and ethGasPrice() are not supported by infura, but why some events are missed on Ganache?.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I have the same with infura.

Comment: Use the wss service instead of https.